# VS Code File Explorer filter not including all matches

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, search, ide

When I click into the VS Code v1.71.2 file explorer, press ctrl+F to open the file explorer search option, and type the name of the file I want to search for, VSCODE only pulls up some of the matches, but not nearly all of them. In fact, it only seems to randomly reveal file matches that I've recently opened or opened the parent folder of. What's with this random behavior? I tried closing and re-opening vscode to no avail. I still only get a couple matches out of 50 files with that name:

[image]

Comment: Update: I just realized the filter is only filtering in folders/subfolders that are 'unfolded' in the File Explorer UI. Eww. That's not desired behavior. Any way to change this or get around this?

Comment: It seems there's not even a good way to unfold all folders (>unfold commands dont do anything). If this isn't a bug, what a useless feature(s) when working on even a small enterprise app!

Comment: have you tried just using command palette? There the whole directory is searched through.

Comment: Command palette only matches filenames. With the explorer filter, folder names are matched as well. But because only expanded nodes of the tree view are matched, then the filter feature becomes much less useful.

Answer (score -1):

Command palette (`Ctrl + P`) does fuzzy search on the entire solution when used without any modifiers.

Note that opening the command palette with `Ctrl + Shift + P` would append the "**>**" modifier and set the palette into command mode.